# ajax request in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

Is it possible to use jquery ajax with jquery mobile?

```
$.ajax({
   url:'/php',
   type:'GET',
   dataType:'json',
   data:{'action':'getData'},
   success: function(result) {
    alert(result);
   },error:function(err){alert(err);}
});
```

this code is failing on button click of jquery mobile(data-role=button)
What is the problem here?
If i run that get request in new tab then it works fine and i can get the response.

Comment: Its possible,wrap it up in function and call it on button click it will work

Comment: yeah i am doing the same.But it is not working . It fails

Comment: You are missing a comma after `data:{'action':'getData'}`

Comment: check console did you get error?

Comment: sorry that is a typo mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax call was failing because of appcache and not because of jquery-mobile. Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

Test that:

```
$.ajax({
  url:'/php',
  type:'GET',
  dataType:'json',
  data:{action:'getData'}
  success: function(result) {
     alert(result);
  },
  error:function(err){alert(err);}
});
```

Comment: If i run that get request in new tab then it works fine and i can get the response.

Comment: This is a problem with your php in these cases.

Comment: I am getting answer from php in new tab . So this is problem in jquery itself right?

Comment: Put a comma after the data line.

Comment: i have comma after data line, typo mistake here